# CyanogenMod comes with inbuilt busybox?

Tags: cyanogenmod, busybox

Does CyanogenMod 11 come with busybox pre-installed, or does it need to be installed separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes cyanogenmod always provides a busybox installation.

The repo manifest file contains an entry as following:

```
<project path="external/busybox" name="CyanogenMod/android_external_busybox"/>
```

You can see it here: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_busybox